# Exporting the data to Excel

Tags: python, excel, formatting

Here is my code:

```
import xlwt
file = 'C://Users/MM/Desktop/'
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sh = wb.add_sheet('S1')

d = [['Numbers','4,849,377','736,732','6,731,484']['Money','$43,253','$70,760','$49,774'],['Decnum','1.22','3.45','9.10']]

for row, nums in enumerate(d):
    for col, value in enumerate(nums):
        sh.write(col, row , value)

wb.save(file +'try.xls')
print('Exported')
```

Following are the things I'm trying to accomplish:

1) Everything in first row needs to be bold and in italics.

2) The width for all the columns needs to be same(fixed).

3) The 'Numbers','Money', and 'Decnum' gives me an error in excel telling me to convert them into numbers with green error arrows.

4) The data needs to centered.

Here is an example of the outlook

[image: <img>http://i59.tinypic.com/dgu48.jpg<img>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [**`replace()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

```
>>> x = '1,2,3'
>>> x.replace(',', '')
'123'

for row, nums in enumerate(d):
    for col, value in enumerate(nums):
        try:
            value = int(value.replace(',', ''))
        except:
            pass
        sh.write(col, row , value)
```

Style formatting:

```
style = xlwt.XFStyle()

font = xlwt.Font()
font.bold = True
style.font = font

sh.write(col, row , value, style=style)
```

**Summarize:**

```
style = xlwt.XFStyle()

font = xlwt.Font()
font.bold = True
style.font = font

for row, nums in enumerate(d):
    for col, value in enumerate(nums):
        try:
            value = int(value.replace(',', ''))
        except:
            pass
        if col == 0:
            sh.write(col, row , value, style=style)
        else:
            sh.write(col, row , value)
```

Another approach is to use **`easyxf()`**:

```
head = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center; font: bold 1,')
common = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;')

for row, nums in enumerate(d):
    for col, value in enumerate(nums):
        try:
            value = int(value.replace(',', ''))
        except:
            pass
        if col == 0:
            sh.write(col, row, value, style=head)
        else:
            sh.write(col, row, value, style=common)
```

*Widths & Heights*

Add that bedore `wb.save()`

```
import itertools

col_width = 26 * 20   

try:
    for i in itertools.count():
        sh.col(i).width = col_width
except ValueError:
    pass
```

---

**Setting cell format**

[Additional formats](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/examples/num_formats.py)

```
num = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;', '#,##')

if col == 0:
    sh.write(col, row, value, style=head)
else:
    if type(value) is int:
        sh.write(col, row, value, style=num)
    else:
        sh.write(col, row, value, style=common)
```

---

Full snippet:

```
import itertools
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
sh = wb.add_sheet('S1')

d = [['Numbers', '4,849,377', '736,732', '6,731,484'],
     ['Letters', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['Colors', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']]


head = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center; font: bold 1,')
common = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;')
num = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;', '#,##')

for row, nums in enumerate(d):
    for col, value in enumerate(nums):
        try:
            value = int(value.replace(',', ''))
        except:
            pass
        if col == 0:
            sh.write(col, row, value, style=head)
        else:
            if type(value) is int:
                sh.write(col, row, value, style=num)
            else:
                sh.write(col, row, value, style=common)

    col_width = 200 * 20

    try:
        for i in itertools.count():
            sh.col(i).width = col_width
    except ValueError:
        pass

wb.save('tryx.xls')
print 'Exported'
```

Comment: Okay. I am getting the first row to have bold text. However, I don't want to replace the commas. I need to keep them. And, what about italics, column width, and centering the data? As I said, it should look like the data in the image.

Comment: @ user3990145:  I got everything except widening the column. I used the second approach of your code; the one with easyxf. Could you please tell me how to widen the columns to a certain width?

Comment: @user5403501 : One last thing if you can please. Okay. In the line `value = int(value.replace(',', ''))`, I replaced that `''` with `','`, so now I am getting commas. However, there still exists a problem which is that in excel, it tells me that the "numbers are stored as text", and gives me an error with those green arrow in the corners. How do I store them as numbers?  Link for the error in image :   http://oi61.tinypic.com/24gojd0.jpg

Comment: @ user3990145:  Are you still trying to get the green arrow problem fixed?

Comment: @user5403501 `value = int(value.replace(',', ''))` there is no any error if we remove commas and cast it to int. So for Excell settings check https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Show-or-hide-the-thousands-separator-b9f8aee0-ef50-42e5-8fd7-6e3ab1493876

Comment: @ user3990145:  Ignore that problem. I want to have the green arrows fixed. I will accept answer I promise.

Comment: @ user3990145:   Thanks!! I truly appreciate that. I hate to say this but the code I have on here doesn't have what my original code. My original code has other two formats, and they are $##,### and #.##    could u please do something for those. Those still has green arrows.

Comment: @user5403501 I have no idea what's wrong with your Excel. That works fine for me. Try to play with cell formatting. Or just disable type this notification in your Excel.

Comment: It works fine for me too. But, as I said the code I copied and pasted here is a decoy of my original. My original and its content that is being exported to excel does not only have numbers as data, but it also has data with $##,### and decimal numbers #.##  How do I fix those two ?

Comment: @user5403501 add verifications in your code. So if it is money format use this style $##,### .

Comment: I have been trying. These are the two numbers I have :                     Format 1-  $43,253   and Format 2-  2.55     The style you suggested does not work. I am just adding on this line `num = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;', '#,##','$##,###')` I found this link where we can get the formatting from but that does not work:  https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/examples/num_formats.py

Comment: @user5403501 `if value == money: mon = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;' ,'$##,###')`; `if value == numbers: num = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;', '#,##')` split it to different format types

Comment: Where do I place that in the code and replace what with that?

Comment: @user5403501 check if `value.startswith('$')`, then remove commas and cast it to `int`, and create money style `mon = xlwt.easyxf('align: horiz center;' ,'$##,###')`. And finally apply it. `sh.write(col, row, value, style=mon)`

Comment: Sorry. I am not getting any new results. I edited my original code. Could you please help me now ? I know you have done more than enough for me. It's just that I want it to be perfect.

Comment: Are you still with me ?

Comment: @user5403501 what is your problem?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I appreciate all your help. Thanks!!